# 3d model in Maya with low quality GPU

Tags: 3d, maya

if I make a ​3d model in Maya with low quality GPU And I Upgrade my GPU will my 3d model from my low-quality GPU will it improve or should I upgrade and then make the 3d model

Comment: The GPU doesn't matter at all. It may change render times but not the model you create.

Comment: so i can  3d model even if my GPU is intel UHD Graphics 617 1536 MB ?

Comment: so your saying the render will change regardless

Comment: The time it takes to render will change. The result should be the same.

Comment: so I should upgrade my GPU And then make the 3d model

Comment: Quality comes from the design of the models, rigging, animation, textures, and shaders. If you ran the original toy story assets through a modern graphics card, you wouldn't suddenly start seeing blood vessels in mr potato man's eyes or anything ;). Don't worry about upgrading your GPU until it starts taking too much time for your renders to finish.

Comment: so im asking because when I open Maya and adding some shape this happens..       .https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqosc0wbjwmhbq5/Screen%20Shot%202019-07-11%20at%209.06.25%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter about time not quality. The quality of the model won't magically get better if you suddenly upgrade your graphics card, but it will render faster. Many deformers and nodes in Maya also utilize GPU to perform faster, so it could also increase how responsive the scene is. I'm assuming Unreal is the same to optimize performance.

If I made an awesome looking model then pass the file to a friend with a garbage system it won't suddenly look ugly. The data that makes the model is still there. Polygons won't suddenly start disappearing! Instead my friend's system may struggle to compute the data and run sluggish.

So in short, if you're able to use the software now without any major speed issues then continue on. If you find your speed is taking too much of a hit then you can consider an upgrade.

Making a model look good isn't about hardware, it's about pure skill and techniques as an artist. A good modeler with old school crap hardware will still outperform a bad modeler with top of the line hardware.

Comment: im saying dos my model render better if I make the model and then use egpu or I need GPU

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqosc0wbjwmhbq5/Screen%20Shot%202019-07-11%20at%209.06.25%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Does it render *better*? No. Will it render faster? Yes. That's your answer!

Comment: Your dropbox link is a screen grab of the viewport. In the end you need to render the image, yes? And the render will NOT change despite of an old/new graphics card. Don't get confused with what's in the viewport vs what the final render will be.

Comment: so if I create model it doesn't matter wen I upgrade my GPU or CPU

Comment: No. What did you think would happen?

Comment: so how can I fix grab of the viewport